# Can I use COUNTIFS where only 1 IF criteria is required?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
          COL A     COL B     COL C
ROW 1     Yes                 Yes
ROW 2     Yes
ROW 3
ROW 4               Yes       Yes
```

I'm trying to write a formula that will count how many rows has at least one column with the value "Yes" in it. I've tried using `COUNTIFS()` with all three columns but that only works if all three columns say "Yes". I want to count a row regardless of how many "Yes" values are in it, as long as there is at least one.

I could achieve this more easily if I added a fourth column that used `IF` statements to look for the YES values and then counted THAT column. However, I'm looking for a single cell solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do it with the following array formula.

```
=SUM(--((A1:A4="Yes")+(B1:B4="Yes")+(C1:C4="Yes")>0))
```

To indicate that it is an array formula, after inputting the formula into Excel, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What happened is `A1:A4` will be expanded into array for evaluation, `A1:A4="Yes"` will be expanded to `{"Yes", "Yes", "", ""} = "Yes"`, which in turns become `{TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE}`.  Excel treats TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0 internally.

Therefore `(A1:A4="Yes")+(B1:B4="Yes")+(C1:C4="Yes")` evaluates to `{2, 1, 0, 2}`.
Next, `{2, 1, 0, 2}` is compared with `>0`, which gives `{TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE}`.
To chance True to 1 and False to 0 for adding, I added a `--` operator (which is literally double negative) to make the array `{1, 1, 0, 1}`.  Summing up `{1, 1, 0, 1}` gives 3.

Anyway, I don't recommend this method if the workbook needs to be shared as this method is not easy to understand; but it would be fun if you understand the underlying mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

If your three columns are **contiguous** then you could use this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(MMULT(0+(A1:C4="Yes"),{1;1;1})>0))`

You need to change the `{1;1;1}` part so that the number of 1s is the same as the number of columns